# Image not loading on bootstrap card on angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am fairly new to angular and I inserted the following bootstrap code into my carousel card component's html file:

```
  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="grey.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The SCSS is:

```
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "../../styles";
```

This is the error I got:

```
http://localhost:4200/grey.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

However, you can see I wrote in the image file correctly: my folders look like this:

[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: try this
    <img class="card-img-top" src="./grey.jpg" alt="Card image cap">

Comment: @Gopal no that doesn't work but putting it in assets works like someone suggested below

Answer (score 2):

just put that img inside assets folder. and just give path `assets/grey.jpg` instead of `localhost:4200/.....` and use `style="background-image: url('assets/grey.jpg')"`

Comment: Why can't we put it inside the component it self?

Comment: angular doesn't looks img inside any other folder other than assets folder, if that makes sense.